# How do I call a non-static method from another class in a non-static method? (java)

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public String recToString (boolean format) {

    Date date = new Date();

        File inputFile = new File ("records.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        if (format == true){
            format = Date1.usFormat();
            format = Date1.usFormat();
        } else {
            format = Date1.euFormat();
        }      
        }
```

I plan to call the usFormat and euFormat.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class Date1 {    
        String month = "";
        String day   = "";
        String year  = "";

        public Date1 (String date)  { 
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/"); 
            month = st.nextToken();
            day   = st.nextToken();
            year  = st.nextToken();
        } //end constructor   

        public  String usFormat () {   
            String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            return date;
        } //end usFormat   


        public String euFormat () { 
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            return date;
        } //end euFormat 
        } //end class
```

Try to ignore any other mistakes please. But if it screws up this and I have to change it to get it, please do tell :)

Thanks.

Comment: format can't meanwhile be a boolean parameter, and the String result from calling euFormat/usFormat.

Comment: yeah, and if it is a `boolean`, you could simply write: `if (format == true)` into `if (format)`, it's more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a `Date1` object and call the methods on that.  You need to do something like

```
...
String dateString = ...
Date1 date1 = new Date1(dateString);
if (format){
  format = date1.usFormat();
} else {
  format = date1.euFormat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i'd typically do the following

```
 format = new Date1(date.toString()).usFormat();
 format = new Date1(date.toString()).usFormat();
```

Not sure why you are not making them static though.

Comment: we had to make it non-static methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:

```
Date1.usFormat();
```

like usFormat is a static method. But, as you already said, it's not.  You need to create an instance of Date1 by doing:

```
Date1 myDate1 = new Date1("01/01/2001");
```

After that you can call either format method with the myDate1 object like:

```
format = myDate1.usFormat();
```